# Is it true that the dot product of two vectors x and y cannot be larger, in absolute value, than the product of their 1-norms?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that the dot product of two vectors x and y cannot be larger, in absolute value, than the product of their 1-norms?

I know for 2-norm it's true since its the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but is it true for any other norm?

Comment: Do you have a particular vector space in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|(x_1,...,x_n)\cdot (y_1,...,y_n)|=|\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_j|\le$$ $$\le \sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|\cdot |y_j|\le$$ $$\le \sum_{j=1}^n\left(|x_j|\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|\right)=$$ $$=(\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|)\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|)=$$ $$=\|(x_1,...,x_n)\|_1\cdot \|(y_1,...,y_n)\|_1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, the $1$-norm is always larger than the $2$-norm, so it trivially holds for the $1$-norm (and any other $p$-norm with $p < 2$) as well.